# CakePHP breadcrumbs configuration

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm creating breadcrumbs for my CakePHP site with HtmlHelper and I need a last crumb to not be a link but have an ID.
 If I use

```
$this->Html->addCrumb($news['News']['title'],null, array('id' => 'crumbselected'));
```

I get my crumb but it is simple text with no html attributes.

If instead of null I add a link everything works fine. But as I said – I need a last crumb to not be a link but have an ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$options` parameter is only used if you are outputting a link. You could try something like this instead:

```
$this->Html->addCrumb('<span id="crumbselected">' . $news['News']['title'] . '</span>',null);
```